# 500 Server Error With Running Flask App With CGI Script

Tags: python, apache, flask, cgi, ionos

I keep receiving a `500 Internal Server Error` with my Python Flask/CGI program.

I am running it on shared hosting, so I followed this tutorial:
https://medium.com/@dorukgezici/how-to-setup-python-flask-app-on-shared-hosting-without-root-access-e40f95ccc819

This is my main python script: (`~/website/mainApp.py`)

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def home():
        return "123 :)"

if __name__ == "__main__":
        app.run()
```

This is my CGI script (`~/website/main.cgi`)

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
sys.path.insert(0, "~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages")

from wsgiref.handlers import CGIHandler
from mainApp import app
CGIHandler().run(app)
```

and this is my .htaccess file (`~/website/.htaccess`):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /main.cgi/$1 [L]
```

This is basically a file tree of it:
[image: Image of file tree 2.0]

This is the error I am getting:

```
Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

Does anyone see where an error may be?

Thanks!

**Edit**: It now has a weird `.pyc` file in it. I didn't add it though.?

Comment: BTW you can safely ignore the `.pyc` file, that's just the bytecode that Python generates.

Answer (score 1):

The contents of your `.cgi` and `.py` files look fine.

The main problem is that the permissions on your `.cgi` file are not correct. Possibly also, the same goes for the `website` directory -- its permissions are not visible in the file view you posted.

You need execution (and read!) permission on the CGI file, and on any directories leading up to it.

In theory, the following, when run from inside the `website` directory, should be sufficient:

```
chmod a+rx . main.cgi
```

Notice the `.` to also apply the command to the current (`website`) directory. This adds read permission and execute permission to the owner, group and others.

If you don't want any permissions applied for the group, then this is sufficient:

```
chmod uo+rx . main.cgi
```

As for the `.htaccess` file, its also valid and would work -- assuming you have [`mod_rewrite`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) enabled on your server. Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869092/how-to-enable-mod-rewrite-for-apache-2-2) post for instructions on enabling that in case you haven't already.

Comment: I update the permissions for the python file, the cgi file, and the directory they are in. I also added `RewriteBase /` to the .htaccess file. However, whenever I go to the URL, it brings me to the default page that IONOS servers, which has sedo parking on it. For some reason, it's not running the FLask. I updated the post.

Comment: I'm not really familiar with IONOS setup. But you need to make sure the `DocumentRoot` is set correctly - to point to `~/website/`.

Comment: By `DocumentRoot`, do you mean `RewriteBase`? @costaparas

Comment: They are two different things - `DocumentRoot` is set in the (global) config, which should point to the server's root directory. (But I suppose you can't change that with IONOS). Maybe try `RewriteBase /website` in your `.htaccess` file instead.

Comment: I did it, and I still get the original problem where it brings me to IONOS's sedo parking page. BTW, in IONOS you can change the website 'target', which is currently pointing towards /website . @costaparas

Answer (score 1):

I changed the shebang at the top of the `main.cgi` file, and it worked.

Before:
`#!/usr/bin/python`

After:
`#!/usr/bin/python3.7`

Comment: Great! Glad it worked for you. Its odd that you didn't see any error message for this in the logs though? And instead, you were redirected to a default IONOS page; strange setup they have.